# Broadcom 440x Ethernet NIC Drivers and Windows Home Server

Tags: drivers, ethernet, windows-home-server, broadcom

I have installed Windows Home Server on an older Dell computer, and it uses a Broadcom 440x Ethernet NIC driver. I have tried all of the drivers listed on their [drivers page](http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/4401.php) to no luck.

The error message I get when trying to install is:

```
The parameter is incorrect
```

I know it is a long shot, but anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the correct driver through [Dell's support site](http://support.dell.com/) -- the OEM driver may have tweaked the default chipset.

If it helps, WHS is based off of Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I have tried this and get an error message on their installer - "this driver is for Windows 2000 and XP only". I have tried the Server 2003 driver from their website and had no luck as well unfortunately.

Comment: What kind of installer?  MSI, exe?  Can you open it with an archive tool (winzip, winrar, 7zip)?

Comment: Ok I have unzipped it, but unfortunately again i get the same error in my original post when trying to install the driver. It only came with Windows 2000 and XP drivers. 2000 one didn't work at all, XP gave the original error. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps in such cases if you run the installation in compatibility mode of Windows XP SP2 (if that's possible on WHS).

Answer (score 0):

You need a HCL driver from [Windows Update Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/)